# Minimal API level 8 vs mipmaps

Tags: android, android-mipmap

I need to support old devices (API 8) because app has users with Android 2.2. But our launcher icon looks awfully on new tablets that uses mip-map icons in the launcher.
Can I use mip-map on old devices (I understand that they doesn't support mip-map but can they recognize resources in the mip-map folder like drawables)?
If they can't then how can I setup build variant to build old version with drawable launcher icon and mip-map?

Comment: you could try to create a drawable-v8 with the old icons and mipmap for the newer devices... that could work

Comment: Yeah, I thinked about it. But how to adapt a manifest?

Comment: *thought Sorry, I bad know English.

Comment: It may be possible to just create `drawable` folders and `mi-map` folders along side each other, where mi-map devices use the correct folder.

Comment: How to adapt so constructions `<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>`?

Comment: good point, what i said must be wrong. if you set mip-map does it not work below v8?

Comment: I found the [solution](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html). It's the most pretty solution that I was able to find.